# How to add List in datatable C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have multiple list of strings with data that I want to print in my datatable in different columns

Here's my code

```
List<string> WareHouseStatus = new List<string>();
List<string> Gulf_IT_Barcode = new List<string>();
List<string> Item_Original_SNO = new List<string>();

DataTable NewTempletLaptop_Excel = new DataTable();
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("WareHouseStatus", typeof(string));
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("Gulf_IT_Barcode", typeof(string));
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("Item_Original_SNO", typeof(string));

foreach (var item in WareHouseStatus)
{
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows.Add(item);
}

foreach (var item in Gulf_IT_Barcode)
{
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows.Add(item);  ///
}
```

My second `foreach` loop adds the item in the same 1st column.

How can I print all these string list in all three columns of the datatable?

Comment: Print to where? what exactly are you trying to make it look like - and what have you tried to do with it?

Comment: i want it to fill these lists in my three diff colunms...e.g List 1 fill in Colunm1 ,  list 2 fill in Colunm 2 ...etc

Comment: Look at your code, you are adding *rows* twice, not *columns*. Use one for-loop, populate the columns with the values and then add the row to the datatable.

Comment: can you show some example?? i want to add lists item in my datatable

Comment: What will happen if you have less values in one list, compared to the other lists?

Comment: no it wont..all list have equall values

Comment: so try something? tell us how it didnt do quite what you thought

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best design I would do, but the answer trying do propose solution with **minimal changes** to the original code.

You have to create the needed numbers of rows, then populate the rows accessing by row index and row column name.

```
List<string> WareHouseStatus = new List<string>() { "1", "11", "111" };
List<string> Gulf_IT_Barcode = new List<string>() { "2", "22", "222" };
List<string> Item_Original_SNO = new List<string>() { "3", "33", "333" };

System.Data.DataTable NewTempletLaptop_Excel = new System.Data.DataTable();
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("WareHouseStatus", typeof(string));
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("Gulf_IT_Barcode", typeof(string));
NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Columns.Add("Item_Original_SNO", typeof(string));

int row = 0; // row index in data
foreach (var item in WareHouseStatus)
{
    // create new row, do it only first time
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows.Add(NewTempletLaptop_Excel.NewRow());
    // set value to the appropriate cell
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows[row]["WareHouseStatus"] = item;
    row++;
}

row = 0;
foreach (var item in Gulf_IT_Barcode)
{
    // set value to the appropriate cell
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows[row]["Gulf_IT_Barcode"] = item;
    row++;
}

row = 0;
foreach (var item in Item_Original_SNO)
{
    // set value to the appropriate cell
    NewTempletLaptop_Excel.Rows[row]["Item_Original_SNO"] = item;
    row++;
}
```

Be aware that it will fail in case your list WareHouseStatus shorter than the other, as its length defines the rows number in the `DataTable`. You can add another logic that handles this case.
In addition the column names shoud be defined once in variables, here I made "copy-paste" of the column name just to be focused on your questions with minimal changes so it will be more clear.

I hope it helps.